# A consequence of the inequality $\pi(x)+\pi(y)\ge\pi(x+y)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Assume that the inequality $\pi(x)+\pi(y)\ge\pi(x+y)$ holds for all integers $x,y>2$ where $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes less than or equal to $x$. Then find all $m$ and $n$ such that, $$\pi(p_n-p_m)>\pi(p_n)-\pi(p_m)$$where $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime.

Now from the hypothesis it easily follows that $$\pi(p_n-p_m)\ge\pi(p_n)-\pi(p_m)$$ but I can't prove that equality cannot occur. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that the question asks only *for which* $n,m$ the inequality holds; it doesn't claim it hold for all such pairs. Note also that the weak inequality you claim to generally hold doesn't hold for all $n, m$: if you let $n=2, m=1$, you get $\pi(3-2) = 0, \pi(3)-\pi(2) = 2-1 =1$. These are just observations; I don't know how to show this.

Comment: @gnometorule: There had been a typo. Please check it.

Comment: I see. So disregard my second point; only the first still stands.

Comment: This is shouting triangle inequality at me.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\pi(p_n) = 1 + \pi(p_{n-1}),$ so the right-hand side of the inequality (assuming $n > m$) is just $\pi(p_n) - \pi(p_m) = 1 + \pi(p_{n-1}) - (1+\pi(p_{m-1}))= \pi(p_{n-m+1}) - 1.$ Hence the inequality reduces to $\pi(p_n - p_m) \ge \pi(p_{n-m+1}),$ which holds iff $p_n-p_m \ge p_{n-m+1},$ since $p_{n-m+1}$ is prime. I doubt there's an easy way to figure out exactly which $m,n$ this holds for.

Comment: I ave figured out a way to prove the inequality for all $m$ and $n$. Observe that by hypothesis,  $\pi(p_m-1)+\pi(p_n-p_m+1)\ge \pi(p_n)$.

Comment: That's not strong enough to give strict inequality. Try, for example, $m=2$ so $p_m = 3$ (in particular then your inequality is not true from the hypothesis). Then the question becomes to determine when $\pi(p_n-3) > \pi(p_n) - 2.$ If $p_n - 2$ and $p_n$ are twin primes, then you're in trouble.

Comment: Also, note that it's possible that $\pi(p_n-p_m+1) = \pi(p_n - p_m) + 1,$ so then the left hand side becomes $\pi(p_m) + \pi(p_n-p_m),$ which doesn't tell you anything new.

Comment: You cannot use $p_m=3$ because $p_m-1$ should be greater than or equal to $3$ by hypothesis.

Comment: that's what i'm saying. Your "proof" doesn't work by my comments above